# How to create a IF NOT EXISTS query in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a IF NOT EXISTS query in Oralce like this:

```
DECLARE
   cnt   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt FROM MY.MYTABLE
    WHERE MYFIELD = 400;

   IF (cnt = 0)
   THEN
      SELECT 'NO ROWS' AS FAIL FROM DUAL;
   ELSE
      SELECT 'SOME ROWS' AS PASS FROM DUAL;
   END IF;
END;
```

but this fails for

```
ORA-06550: line 9, column 7:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
ORA-06550: line 11, column 7:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
```

Why, what is wrong with this query?

Comment: The error messages gave you all the info you needed: `line 9, column 7` and `line 11, column 7`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use into to assign value to variable.

```
DECLARE
   cnt   NUMBER;
   res   NVARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt FROM MY.MYTABLE
    WHERE MYFIELD = 400;

   IF (cnt = 0)
   THEN
      SELECT 'NO ROWS' INTO RES FROM DUAL;
   ELSE
      SELECT 'SOME ROWS' INTO RES FROM DUAL;
   END IF;
END;
```

Also you can directly assign value to variable like

```
IF (cnt = 0)
       THEN
          res := 'NO ROWS';
       ELSE
          res := 'SOME ROWS';
       END IF;
```

Best way is just using this sql

```
SELECT DECODE(COUNT(*), 0, 'NO ROWS','SOME ROWS')  FROM MY.MYTABLE
    WHERE MYFIELD = 400;
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer this way of checking for existence:

```
declare
  dummy      varchar2(1);
begin
  select null into dummy
  from MY.MYTABLE
  where MYFIELD = 400
    and rownum = 1;

  dbms_output.put_line('some rows'); -- some rows
exception
  when no_data_found then
    dbms_output.put_line('no rows'); -- no rows
end;
```

in my opinion it is better because count() can work quite slow for big amounts of data.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message indicates you need a variable into which you can select the value:

```
select 'NO ROWS' as fail into v_status from dual;
```

Of course, you need to previously declare the variable:

```
declare
    v_status varchar2(10);
...
```

But, it is probably easier to just assign the value to the variable:

```
v_status := 'NO ROWS'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL> create table t (x int);


SQL> insert into t values(1);


SQL> commit;

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2   res varchar2(10);
  3  begin
  4    select nvl((select 'SOME ROWS' from t where x =1 and rownum <=1), 'NO ROWS')
  5    into res
  6    from dual;
  7    dbms_output.put_line(res);
  8  end;
  9  /
SOME ROWS                                                                       

SQL> declare
  2   res varchar2(10);
  3  begin
  4    select nvl((select 'SOME ROWS' from t where x = 2 and rownum <=1), 'NO ROWS')
  5    into res
  6    from dual;
  7    dbms_output.put_line(res);
  8  end;
  9  /
 NO ROWS
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a little bit strange maybe, but I prefer not to use
`and rownum=1` but `and rownum < 2;` and never using exception as part of business logic.

```
declare
  cnt   NUMBER;
  res   NVARCHAR2(50);
begin
  select COUNT(*) 
  into cnt
  from MY.MYTABLE
  where MYFIELD = 400
    and rownum < 2;

  IF (cnt = 0) THEN
    RES := 'NO ROWS';
  ELSE
    RES :='SOME ROWS';
  END IF;
end;
```